# Push a button in another program using python

Tags: python, automation, external

I need to have my python program interact with another [closed source program](http://www.alvgmbh.de/Products/Software/CorrSoftware/corrsoftware.html). Specifically, I need the python program to be able to "push" the start button in order to tell the program to start collecting data, and to "push" the save button and tell it where to put the save file at a later time. This is so I can automate a complex series of operations, the data collection phase of which can only be controlled from this operating software (doing it manually involves a person sitting around doing nothing but pushing a repetitive series of buttons for 4-5 hours). I believe this should be possible, but I cannot figure out how to do it (made more complicated by the entire thing needing to run on a windows 2000 box, since the card being operated is on an ISA bus and can't physically be put into anything that can run a newer OS). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Using the Python bindings for the Win32 API might help (of course you need to know how to use the Win32 API): https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Sikuli to detect the button positions and press them. It pushes the button inside a VNC window to the other machine. Wrote all the GUI controls in the Sikuli Script, then called the script from within python as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no API for that program you could use python to steer your mouse directly.

Comment: use for example the modules "win32api" and "win32con" with methods win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)) and win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENT_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)

Comment: That might work for the start button, but windows likes to pop subwindows like the save as dialogue in different places, so using that type of absolute setup to deal the save dialogue would be hard.